# What does "inf" mean in German dictionaries?

Tags: dictionary, abbreviation

The dictionary listing for [versieben](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/versieben) has:

> **versieben**    ver•sie•ben     ( **versiebt**    ptp)    vt
>
> inf   (=vergessen)   to forget
>
> (=verlieren)   to lose
>
> (=verpfuschen)   to make a mess of *inf*

There are two *inf*'s in here. What do they mean? I've tried to find an answer in the dictionary website as well as using Google, but couldn't find one.

Comment: 'inf' means: Infinitiv/ infinitive

Comment: Wenn "inf" wirklich "Infinitiv" bedeuten würde, würde es groß geschrieben.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't found any explanation of abbreviations on that site, but having skimmed some entries I suppose that **inf** stands for **informal**.

I guess the first **inf** belongs to the German term *versieben* and the second one to the English *to make a mess of*.

**Edit: How *inf* possibly was created**
If you submit entries to that site, you can add some optional (tag-like) information. There are some pre-built tags that can be used but also a blank field for custom-made tags. **inf** seems to be a custom-made tag. So maybe the explanation of **inf** as **informal** is not globally true on that site.

<sup>I think that there is little organization which tags are used and how they are formatted because every user can enter new ones as they please.</sup>

Comment: Wofür ist denn der Edit gut?

Comment: @Em1: Um zu zeigen, dass die tatsächlich gemeinte Bedeutung von jedem Benutzer abhängt, der einen Wörterbucheintrag einsendet. Um zu zeigen, dass es auf der Seite keine globale Bedeutung von _inf_ gibt. Einer könnte es als Kurzform für _informal_ einstellen, der andere für irgendetwas anderes. Der eine User könnte etwas als _slang_ oder _vulgar_ kennzeichnen, der andere entscheidet sich für einen _informal_-Tag

Comment: Danke, jetzt hab ich es auch verstanden :)

Comment: Maybe you could add that the German word for informal would be "informell" and that usually "umgangssprachlich/ugs." would be used.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it means "informal" and is an indication of language level. On other entries you can find e.g. "sl" (slang) and "vulg" (vulgar).

Answer (score 2):

Abbreviations used in dictionaries are listed in dictionaries in the introductory pages. The first thing to do when you use a dictionary is to see what is in the introductory pages and what is in the appendix. In an English dictionary inf can either mean informal or infinitive.

From what you have indicated in your question I can see that your dictionary says:
versieben can mean in informal language to forget or to make a mess of something.

Answer (score -4):

*Inf* means *Infinitiv* in German dictionaries, which means the same thing as the English word *infinitive*, which is the modus of the verb.

Comment: But why should it mark only the first of 3 meanings, and why is it behind "to make a mess of", but not "to forget" and "to lose"?

Comment: Infinitiv is not a mood. Moods are Indikativ and Konjunktiv (and some more).